# Owl Carousel Slider JS Error - Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to get this slider working for 2 days now and I can't figure it out. I have tired changing the JS library and check all the CSS and JS roots they seem to be fine to me. but its come up with these errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined owl.carousel.min.js:47
>
> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function:99

View my code here: http://pastebin.com/rY7fUVxU

Slider Site: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include jquery file before the plugin files.

**Change this:**

```
 <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**to:**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Wow that was it haha. New it would be something really simple, Thank You.

Comment: @K K. thank you. i also got my solution from your answer